# PHP ksort for multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I would like to apply `ksort` in a multi-dimensional array. The goal is to sort numeric index for each level.

I tried to do a function to do this but it does not work.

```
function ksort_r( array &$array ){   /* ksort() for multi-dimensional array*/
    ksort( $array );
    foreach ( $array as $key=>$item ){
        if( is_array( $item ) ){
            ksort_r( $item );
        }
    }
}
```

**example**

```
$array = array( 
   1 => array(
        "columns" => array(
             2 => array(),
             0 => array(),
             1 => array(),
        )
   ),
   0 => array(
        "columns" => array(
             2 => array(),
             1 => array(),
             0 => array(),
        )
   )
)

output wishes :

array( 
   0 => array(
        "columns" => array(
             0 => array(),
             1 => array(),
             2 => array(),
        )
   ),
   1 => array(
        "columns" => array(
             0 => array(),
             1 => array(),
             2 => array(),
        )
   )
)
```

Comment: this question have been asked like 1000 times in here... maybe use search instead of asking it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass the value in `foreach` as reference too:

```
foreach ( $array as $key=> &$item ) {
```

Or update the array index with the sorted `$item`:

```
ksort_r($item);
$array[$key] = $item;
```